# Phaser crashes to null window.computedStyle() with Firefox (hidden Iframe)

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

All Phaser game-engine games seem to crash with the following error, but only with Firefox when an `iframe` containing the actual Phaser game is hidden due to a pre-game video ad being displayed.

> Type Error "window.computedStyle() is null"

Any workarounds?

Comment: You're going to need to provide some code. Based upon what you've provided, I would guess the logic around hiding the iframe. Version of Phaser (2 or 3) would also be helpful, although I don't know that it's needed.

Answer (score 1):

I think You misspelled the error: it's "window.getComputedStyle()".

Try using this piece of code:

```
    if (/firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent)){
   window.oldGetComputedStyle = window.getComputedStyle;
   window.getComputedStyle = function (element, pseudoElt) {
      var t = window.oldGetComputedStyle(element, pseudoElt);
      if (t === null) {
         return {
            getPropertyValue: function(){}
         };
      } else{
         return t;
      }
   };
}
```

Comment: Thanks, should this code be located inside the iframe page,  where the phaser.js is included?

Comment: It should, I guess